# How to use Mac Mini as an APNS server for Push Notifications

Tags: mac-mini, osx-server, notifications, apns

I have looked for it everywhere, I can't find any clue where to start or how to do it.

I have an Apple Mac Mini with OSX Server that I would like to use as an APNS server to send push notifications for my iPhone application. I'm currently using my Macbook for the sandbox gateway through terminal running a php script.

What I did/have:

- Generated development/production certificates.
- pem/p12 files.
- PHP Script for sending.

If it can't be done on a Mac Mini Server. How would I pull it off from shared hosting or dedicated server? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted the Mac Mini and reinstalled OSX 10.10, as deleting all files for OSX Server simply just doesn't work.

I followed the following tutorial : [Mac OSX Apache Setup with PHP](http://getgrav.org/blog/mac-os-x-apache-setup-multiple-php-versions)

*Note:* To make your Mac Mini a web server, don't install OSX Server at all, it's mostly designed for company workspace to setup calenders, VPN, email servers etc.